# ArgumentOutOfRangeException on a ForEachAsync using Partitioner

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, foreach

To set the context, the application is running on a server where +-20 other apps are doing some multithreading but this process is only for 2 apps on  the server. I never had this kind of error on other apps and it all uses the ForEachAsync method. On this particular app, I had to add some multithreading and I sometimes get this error when I use the ForEachAsync :

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: partitionCount
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner.DynamicPartitionerForIEnumerable`1.GetOrderablePartitions(Int32 partitionCount)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner`1.GetPartitions(Int32 partitionCount)
   at Common.AsyncHelper.ForEachAsync[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 taskSelector, Int32 maxParallelism) in ...\AsyncHelper.cs:line 15
```

Here is the method :

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> taskSelector, int maxParallelism)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(maxParallelism)
        select Task.Run(async delegate {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await taskSelector(partition.Current);
        }));
}
```

And here is how I use it :

```
int parallel = list.Count() < 8 ? list.Count() : 8;

await list.ForEachAsync(async a => await Process(param1, param2),parallel);
```

Do I use to much parallelism? edit : Looks like the empty list was the issue.

Here is a minimal, working example :

Here is my AsyncHelper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Common
{
    public static class AsyncHelper
    {
        public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> taskSelector, int maxParallelism)
        {
            return Task.WhenAll(
                from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(maxParallelism)
                select Task.Run(async delegate {
                    using (partition)
                        while (partition.MoveNext())
                            await taskSelector(partition.Current);
                }));
        }        
    }
}
```

And what I want to do is process a list and set the result in another list with max // = 8:

```
var temp = new ConcurrentBag<TempResponse>();
int parallel = 1;
if(someList.Any(c => c.Valid))
    parallel = someList.Count(c => c.Valid) < 8 ? someList.Count(c => c.Valid)  : 8;

await someList.ForEachAsync(async a => temp.Add(await Process(a.Condition, a.State, a.Name)),parallel);
```

Comment: try to put ".ToArray()" after .GetPartitions(maxParallelism) what will happen? Also the problem is inside method GetPartiions - so we need it's code to investigate

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using `Parallel.ForEach`? It already partitions the data based on the data size and core count *and* allows you to set the DOP. If you don't want to block waiting for it, run it inside a `Task.Run()`. This won't waste threads - Parallel.For uses the *current* thread as well as threads from the threadpool

Comment: In this cas I really want to set manually the parallelism, this is why I use this method

Comment: @Gun then just set the ParallelismOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism parameter in `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: @Gun what are you *really* trying to do though? It sounds like you want to process batches of tasks at a time, not in parallel. That's more suited to ActionBlock<T>. You can set a DOP to the ActionBlock and just start pumping messages to it. It will only process as many messages in parallel as the DOP specifies. You can also set a limit to its input buffer to avoid flooding it with unprocessed messages

Comment: @Gun if you want each task to process a batch of data at a time you can put a BatchBlock before the ActionBlock

Comment: @Panagiotis kanavos Thanks for all your comments. Honestly I was not aware about the Parallel.For and did not make the class AsyncHelper (where the ForEachAsync is done). We use this method at several places, this is why I used this method, too.
Let me check about ActionBlock and I will update the post to set a complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error just means you are passing `0` as `maxParallelism` to your function.

```
int parallel = list.Count() < 8 ? list.Count() : 8;
```

Can be zero if target `list` is empty, and zero is invalid value for `Partitioner.Create(...).GetPartitions()` call.

So, just check if list is empty and if it is - do nothing (no reason to call `ForEachAsync` on it).